# How to debug dpkg configure error in subprocess post-installation?

Tags: dpkg

In short: I am trying to install spamassassin but dpkg returns only with:

```
dpkg: error processing spamassassin (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I have tried to find more information about what is going wrong but I cannot find anywhere any useful logging.

In /var/crash a spamassassin crashreport is generated but this gives only old dpkg errors and:

```
 Start-Date: 2014-02-17  19:18:13
 Commandline: apt-get install spamassassin
AptOrdering:
 spamassassin: Configure
 amavisd-new-postfix: Configure
```

Followed by dmesg logging from startup. 
Amavis gives an error because dependency spamassassin is not configured.

I checked the log files:

```
apt history.log
apt term.log
dpkg.log
syslog.log
```

but no additional information.

I tried dpkg -D with all possible octals but I find nothing useful about what could go wrong.

Lots of questions and possible solutions have been written about dpkg errors and many I have tried, but with no additional information I do not have the feeling I am getting anywhere.

**Surely there must be somewhere a possibility to read what is going wrong or to crank up some logging so it will be logged?**

Comment: You have to scroll up in your terminal and see the specific error, in the message you saw.  To debug these, you have to see what the *exact* error was that triggered this.

Comment: there should be a description in the terminal, have you looked into  /var/log/spamassassin/spamd.log ?

Comment: I have plowed through all logs, purged, redone installation in many different ways. All to find a bit more information about the error, but I can not find any. Spamd.log is not being made yet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution for this problem. Thought I was unable to crank up the logging to get more data, the data already presented had the clue to the problem.

```
dpkg: error processing spamassassin (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

says dpkg encountered an error processing spamassassin while running configure. Next line tels us the post-installation script did not finish correct.

In the **/var/lib/dpkg/info** dir we can locate the script files of dpkg, the file: **spamassassin.postinst** gives us the script file which generated the error.

Within this file we know we have to look at the code runned by configure:

> if [ "$1" = "configure" ]; then

and after some debugging I found out the line:

> su debian-spamd -c "sa-update --gpghomedir /var/lib/spamassassin/sa-update-keys \
>           --import /usr/share/spamassassin/GPG.KEY"

returned exit code 1 (run command @commandline and use echo $? next to get the exit code)

The problem was that the user debian-spamd already existed on my system but its login shell was /bin/false. Su-ing with /bin/false returns without any message but exitcode 1.

Adding **-s /bin/sh** to the command solved the problem though in the end I did alter the login shell of the user to stay in sync with future updates.

Comment: I had a similar issue to you. With the installer just flat failing. Mine turned out to be an issue with installing the latest version from debian-backports for wheezy. It turned out that they changed the post install script to have a 'su - $OWNER -c "sa-update ...' call which did a full login shell exec to /bin/sh which was incompatible with our /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d files. removing the '-' making it "su $OWNER -c ...." fixed it for me

Comment: I dont have exact problem but your debugging hints helped me lot! thanks!

Comment: > Adding -s /bin/sh to the command

To which command?

Answer (score 16):

Generally to debug such issues, you would edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/spamassassin.postinst` (or `.preinst`, pr `.prerm` or `.postrm`; depending on which one is failing) and change `#!/bin/sh` at the top line to `#!/bin/sh -x` (same thing if it `bash` instead: just add `-x`)

That would provide you with line-by-line debug of shell script, so you could tell where it exits with non-zero code (causing the installation/upgrade to fail).

It would probably require at least some shell scripting skills to debug, though.

Comment: how to prevent `dpkg -i xyz.deb` from overriding the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/xyz.postinst` again after I edited it for debugging purposes? Everytime I edit it, dpkg will undo my edits :(

Comment: @ElectRocnic you'd unpack `.deb` archive with `ar(1)`, then use `tar(1)` to unpack `control.tar.gz` contained within, and then edit `.postinst` and other control scripts to your liking, and use `tar` and `ar` to repack back `.deb` file. Alternatively, get the source (with `apt-get source` or like) and edit `postinst` files and and rebuild package with `debuild(1)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1000830#30), like the [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/735568/322045), we see how to add debugging code, (e.g., "set -x") to an /var/lib/dpkg/info/* file, BUT without having it get overwritten just before execution!:

```
  # dpkg --unpack /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-pc_2.06-2_amd64.deb
  ... edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst ...
  # dpkg --configure grub-pc
```