# Dependency errors after installing and attempting to remove Google Chrome

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome, dpkg

So ubuntu worked perfectly for me for a while. I tried to download Google Chrome and accidentally downloaded the 32 bit version. Went back and tried to download the 64-bit (stupidly without deleting the 32 bit), and started having problems getting error messages related to `google-chrome-stable`.

My next step was to purge everything I have on Ubuntu related to Chrome, but I'm still getting these errors and, given that I'm still a newbie to Linux, I'm really lost for what to do right now.

Now, I can't download anything via the command line. For example, I just tried downloading Ubuntu's version of f.lux and got the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gcc-4.8-base:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386
  libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcolord1:i386 libcups2:i386
  libcurl3:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libdbusmenu-glib4:i386
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgcrypt11:i386
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386
  libgpg-error0:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libidn11:i386 libjasper1:i386 libjbig0:i386
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libmbim-glib0 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libqmi-glib0 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librtmp0:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386
  libthai0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
  libwind0-heimdal:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386
  libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxft2:i386
  libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  libxrender1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxtst6:i386 usb-modeswitch
  usb-modeswitch-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libappindicator1 libglade2-0 libindicator7
Suggested packages:
  python-gtk2-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-chrome-stable:i386 libappindicator1:i386 libindicator7:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libappindicator1 libglade2-0 libindicator7 python-appindicator python-glade2
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 3 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 53.4 kB/101 kB of archives.
After this operation, 185 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libglade2-0 amd64 1:2.6.4-2 [44.6 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-glade2 amd64 2.24.0-3ubuntu3 [8,744 B]
Fetched 53.4 kB in 0s (159 kB/s)         
(Reading database ... 170838 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing google-chrome-stable (46.0.2490.71-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Removing libappindicator1 (12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing libindicator7 (12.10.2+14.04.20141007.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I need to be able to download packages without problems. Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT:** Additionally, when I tried to update the software, I got this message:

```
**THE PACKAGE SYSTEM IS BROKEN.** 
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
```

But when I run `apt-get install -f`, I get the following output:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Response from `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libcolord1:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libmbim-glib0 libqmi-glib0 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
  libxkbcommon0:i386 usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up google-chrome-stable (46.0.2490.71-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Response to `sudo apt-get update` was very long, so I shortened it to just the error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fabricesp/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fabricesp/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Error for install-f:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up google-chrome-stable (46.0.2490.71-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And error for dist-upgrade:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up google-chrome-stable (46.0.2490.71-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Error for `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all google-chrome-stable`

```
Removing google-chrome-stable (46.0.2490.71-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

In response to A.B's suggestions, after running
`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable*.prerm`, I then ran `sudo apt-get install -f` and got the same answer I've been getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libcolord1:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libmbim-glib0 libqmi-glib0 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
  libxkbcommon0:i386 usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up google-chrome-stable (46.0.2490.71-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422264/how-to-debug-dpkg-configure-error-in-subprocess-post-installation)

Comment: type in terminal sudo apt-get autoclean then type in sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable  Then install Chrome

Comment: When I try to purge after autocleaning I'm still getting the same damn error "Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
"

Comment: I have changed the steps in my answer a little bit. Start again at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: What a stupid error message,right? Why is it not telling us what is going wrong.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like your sources file is corrupted and there are broken packages. Remove the corrupted source file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, and type in:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

This will open software-properties-gtk and a new `sources.list` will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

[image]

[How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Step 2 
Open up a Terminal and type in

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Then install Chrome.

**Edit**

I joined Sunny in a chat to help him fix the problem and deleting `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/google-chrome` by running

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/google-chrome
```

and running

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

has fixed the problem and  Sunny has said that the errors are not happening any more.

Comment: I added the results to those commands in the question above.

Comment: just edited my post. hope it helps

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting sudo: rm/etc/apt/sources.list: command not found

Comment: "sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list" you need to add a space sudo rm (space) /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I got these messages:
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

Comment: And when I pressed revert and then ran "sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable" I got the same error

Comment: run sudo software-properties-gtk Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list

Comment: Then go to step 2

Comment: Followed this procedure exactly. Does not work for me.

Comment: My error is still : Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30571/discussion-between-sunny-and-neil).

Comment: I know this answer is slightly old, but thanks a tonne for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

Well, after extension searching and finding things I already tried, I went to where the phpmyadmin.prerm, phpmyadmin.postrm, etc scripts where and deleted them manually.

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/

ls -l phpmyadmin.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 2008-03-05 21:42 phpmyadmin.conffiles
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 287 2008-03-05 21:42 phpmyadmin.config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33524 2008-08-06 11:31 phpmyadmin.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51996 2008-03-05 21:42 phpmyadmin.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3286 2008-03-05 21:42 phpmyadmin.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1762 2008-03-05 21:42 phpmyadmin.postrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1762 2008-08-06 09:12 phpmyadmin.postrm.orig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 339 2008-03-05 21:42 phpmyadmin.preinst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22441 2008-03-05 21:42 phpmyadmin.templates
```

then I deleted those files

```
sudo rm -r phpmyadmin.*
```

then I ran

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

I wanted to see if the package was still around, so I ran

sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin

I got the response that the package was not installed so it couldn't not be removed.

FINALLY!

So from there I just ran

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I hope this does help someone, because I look to Ubuntu forums for a lot of answers.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the below commands to get rid of from the E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

step 1:

```
sudo apt --purge remove unattended-upgrades
```

Here unattended-upgrades is "error processing package name". You can replace it with your error processing package name.

step 2:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

step 3:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

The removal of Chrome fails, because there is a problem with the pre-removal script. Remove the script via

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable*.prerm
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable*.postinst
```

and start the removal again via

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get install -f
```

For a better understanding read my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/687321/367165).

---

And the second problem, the PPA ppa:fabricesp/ppa has no packages for Trusty. Therefore use

```
sudo add-apt-repository --r ppa:fabricesp/ppa
```

to remove the PPA. `ppa-purge` doesn't works in this case.

Comment: I edited my question to address these suggestions. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try is to reconfigure the package database. Probably the database got corrupted while installing a package.
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`