# apt-get error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, ros

I am not able to install anything because of the above error.

Output of sudo apt-get -f install is as follows:

```
ubuntu@rudrabot:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ros-indigo-librealsense (1.12.0-0trusty-20161223-214957-0800) ...
modinfo: ERROR: Module uvcvideo not found.
dpkg: error processing package ros-indigo-librealsense (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-indigo-realsense-camera:
 ros-indigo-realsense-camera depends on ros-indigo-librealsense; however:
Package ros-indigo-librealsense is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-indigo-realsense-camera (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-indigo-turtlebot-    bringup:
     ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup depends on ros-indigo-realsense-camera;     however:
  Package ros-indigo-realsense-camera is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a     followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error     message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                Errors were     encountered while processing:
 ros-indigo-librealsense
 ros-indigo-realsense-camera
 ros-indigo-turtlebot-bringup
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried a couple of solutions like editing the status file or the one mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688338/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-related-to-google-chrom) but of no use.

Comment: can you install `sudo apt-get install aptitude`?

Comment: no, got the same error for this.