# Error intalling package

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, dpkg, plymouth

I have only been using Linux for a few months and am not too familiar with different errors. I have never seen this one before and have no idea how to make sense of it. I am trying to install valgrind to test a couple programs for memory leaks. I have tried installing it two different ways and get a similar but different error both ways.

When I try installing it with `sudo apt install valgrind` this is the error I get:

```
(Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  valgrind-dbg kcachegrind alleyoop valkyrie
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  valgrind
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 225 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 66.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service vpnagentd_init if started
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried installing with `sudo apt-get install valgrind`, and I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  valgrind-dbg kcachegrind alleyoop valkyrie
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  valgrind
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 225 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 66.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting vpnagentd_init depends on ondemand and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service vpnagentd_init and ondemand if started
insserv:  loop involving service ondemand at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service vpnagentd_init at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) \[related to google chrome\]](http://askubuntu.com/questions/688338/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-related-to-google-chrom)

Comment: You installed something called "vpnagentd_init". Perhaps you installed some VPN software? It's poorly written, and that lack of quality means that the system cannot determine when it should be started or stopped automatically. Either uninstall the software or fix it's init script. If you decide to fix it, and need help doing so, that's a whole different question.