# Cant install anything in termux using ubuntus root access terminal too install pkg from github that require root

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

```
root@localhost:~# apt update && apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports disco-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports disco-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports disco-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
E: Setting in Start via TCSAFLUSH for stdin failed! - tcsetattr (13: Permission denied)
Setting up udisks2 (2.8.2-1) ...
Failed to scan devices: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
 installed udisks2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libfprint0:armhf (1:0.8.2-3) ...
Failed to scan devices: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libfprint0:armhf (--configure):
 installed libfprint0:armhf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-daemons:
 gvfs-daemons depends on udisks2; however:
  Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-daemons (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-backends:
 gvfs-backends depends on gvfs-daemons (= 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-backends (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fprintd:
 fprintd depends on libfprint0 (>= 1:0.4.0); however:
  Package libfprint0:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fprintd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-fprintd:armhf:
 libpam-fprintd:armhf depends on fprintd (= 0.8.1-1); however:
  Package fprintd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-fprintd:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs:armhf:
 gvfs:armhf depends on gvfs-daemons (<< 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1.1~); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.
 gvfs:armhf depends on gvfs-daemons (>= 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-fuse:
 gvfs-fuse depends on gvfs (= 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package gvfs:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-fuse (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udisks2
 libfprint0:armhf
 gvfs-daemons
 gvfs-backends
 fprintd
 libpam-fprintd:armhf
 gvfs:armhf
 gvfs-fuse
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@localhost:~#
```

Here's a little bit more detail. I run Ubuntu on Termux after installing it I was able to use it normally. After a while however this popped up. I tried everything I could find on Google and some ideas of my own. This is preventing me from updating and upgrading or installing things from GitHub such as sherlock, but I can't use it as I need to install python-pip, but then I get this error message when trying to install anything.

```
root@localhost:~# apt install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-pip is already the newest version (18.1-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
E: Setting in Start via TCSAFLUSH for stdin failed! - tcsetattr (13: Permission denied)
Setting up udisks2 (2.8.2-1) ...
Failed to scan devices: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
 installed udisks2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libfprint0:armhf (1:0.8.2-3) ...
Failed to scan devices: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libfprint0:armhf (--configure):
 installed libfprint0:armhf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-daemons:
 gvfs-daemons depends on udisks2; however:
  Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-daemons (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-backends:
 gvfs-backends depends on gvfs-daemons (= 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-backends (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fprintd:
 fprintd depends on libfprint0 (>= 1:0.4.0); however:
  Package libfprint0:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fprintd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-fprintd:armhf:
 libpam-fprintd:armhf depends on fprintd (= 0.8.1-1); however:
  Package fprintd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-fprintd:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs:armhf:
 gvfs:armhf depends on gvfs-daemons (<< 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1.1~); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.
 gvfs:armhf depends on gvfs-daemons (>= 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-fuse:
 gvfs-fuse depends on gvfs (= 1.40.1-1ubuntu0.1); however:
  Package gvfs:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-fuse (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udisks2
 libfprint0:armhf
 gvfs-daemons
 gvfs-backends
 fprintd
 libpam-fprintd:armhf
 gvfs:armhf
 gvfs-fuse
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@localhost:~#
```

I really cant understand this problem as nothing works  i am using termux on android not rooted to get into ubuntu i use cd termux-ubuntu then ./start-ubuntu.sh from there i can get a root terminal to use tools such as Tool-X for pen testing my network phone labtop and my webservers using apache2 ect. I dont know if this matters but i also have kali installed on termux i can get into that using kalistart in my terminal to also get root access but all my tools are on the ubuntu terminal. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) \[Related to KVM\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011834/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-related-to-kvm)

Comment: Or is this your problem? https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1359

Comment: This might can help you.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/31667/what-does-no-apport-report-written-because-maxreports-is-reached-already-mean

Answer (score 0):

Termux works on  on Android 5.0 or later, however here's an excerpt from the [Termux wiki FAQ.](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ)

```
On recent Android versions, the write access to the external SD card is done over Storage Access Framework. It is not possible to provide it's API to the command line programs.


There several solutions:

    Use root for putting necessary files to external SD.
    Use custom ROMs. Some of them have disabled SD card access restriction, so you can freely access your external SD card.
    Use a Termux private directory on the external SD card. Usually, it's path should be /storage/XXXX-XXXX/Android/data/com.termux.
```

and [Differences from Linux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux)

```
Termux only has a few packages. Can I use the Debian repositories instead?

No, you can't.

There are major differences between Termux and regular Linux distributions, and packages from these repositories won't work. See Differences from Linux for more information.
```

All these things considered, it's not surprising that you are unable to update Ubuntu packages on Termux as updating packages under Ubuntu requires root access and since the [FSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout) isn't followed under Termux the Ubuntu package systems are unable to place things where they need to be.

There may be away to work around this by utilizing `proot` under Termux, but as AskUbuntu is an Ubuntu focused site you are likely to get better results getting questions about Termux answered at our sister site https://android.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps by reviewing the [Termux Wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page)

Sources:

https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/FAQ

https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux

[How to understand the Ubuntu file system layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout)