# Unable to install new package or update existing ones on 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, kernel, dpkg

I am unable to install new packages or update existing packages to to Linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic, Linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic and Linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic. [Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3StkV.png)

I have tried the solutions provided here, but it is not resolving the problem: [I am having a problem with the package manager on 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040684/i-am-having-a-problem-with-the-package-manager-on-18-04-lts)

Is there way I can fix this problem without formatting my PC? Thanks

EDIT: Full Message on running `sudo apt update`:

> `sudo apt update
>   Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [235 B]
>   Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
>
>     Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
>   Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
>   Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
>   Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
>
>   Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>
>   Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
>   Get:4 http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease [2,592 B]
>
>   Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
>   Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
>
>   Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
>
>   Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu (lsb_release InRelease
>
>   Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
>   Hit:13 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
>
>   Hit:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
>   Err:4 http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease
>
>     The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A
>   Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeal-developers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>
>   Err:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu (lsb_release Release
>
>     404  Not Found [IP: 52.222.253.156 443]
>   Reading package lists... Done
>
>   E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
>   E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
>   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>   W: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A
>   E: The repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease' is not signed.
>   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>   E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu (lsb_release Release' does not have a Release file.
>   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: You might have to change the main repository server as well as performing the solution you tried above.

Comment: I see two problems on your screenshot. 1) You seem to have deleted all your sources. Your system doesn't know where to get new packages from. https://askubuntu.com/a/1040799/19626 will fix that. 2) You seem to have specified kernels to install. Bad idea - let apt do that for you. Those packages are not in the Ubuntu repos anymore anyway. Use `apt-mark` to change those kernel packages to 'remove' status, so apt won;t try to install them anymore.

Comment: Your actual problem seems to occur during the update process, but this can't be seen on your screenshot.  Please run `sudo apt update`, highlight and copy the text, and paste the text into your question (rather than using a screen shot!)

Comment: Charles Green, I made an edit and added the full text on running `sudo apt update`

Comment: I tried all the help provided above but it didn't work. I finally fixed it by following the instructions here: [Ubuntu fix broken packages](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/) to edit the dpkg status file manually.

Comment: @Christian Can you post an answer for what exactly was done to fix the problem? Thank you.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I ran `sudo apt upgrade` to know the packages causing the problem. Those packages are no longer available in the Ubuntu repos anymore, but each time I try to install a new package they are always included along with the packages to be installed. So I ran `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status `, created a backup of the dpkg status file and then removed the offending packages manually.

Comment: You should always use `sudo -H gedit` instead of `sudo gedit`. But I had meant to say you should post an answer to your own question below. Not post a comment. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I am a little new to AskUbuntu. This is my first post here. Thanks for the heads up, I will keep this in mind on my next post/answer.