# Errors were encountered while processing: libtk8.6:amd64 tk8.6-blt2.5

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Every time I try to install any using apt-get install, I get the error saying

> `Errors were encountered while processing:
>    libtk8.6:amd64
>    tk8.6-blt2.5
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I am getting the same error on trying `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic`, which I was doing in an attempt to fix the issue according to the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040684/i-am-having-a-problem-with-the-package-manager-on-18-04-lts). I had gotten this error first while trying to install cd CLI using

> `$ wget -q -O - https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian/cli.cloudfoundry.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
>   $ echo "deb https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources`

Any solutions are appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] the question and paste the full error message. dpkg for almost every error shows `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I try to install packages I get similar errors. Here is my process for resolving those:

- If step 1 succeeds, break.
- If step n succeeds, go to step 1.
- If step n fails, go to step n+1.

---

**Steps**

1. `sudo apt install package-i-want`

   - dependency `X` failed or erred in some way
2. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. `sudo apt -f install`
4. `sudo apt install --reinstall X`
5. Go to step 1