# initramfs error when installing / updating

Tags: apt, initramfs

I've been having an error when updating or running any `apt` command for a week or so. 
Upgrading to LTS 18.04 hasn't resolved it, nor has removing all old kernels.
Space isn't an issue either.

Attempting to reinstall `initramfs` doesn't work.
Error I get is:

```
   Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic (4.15.0-47.50) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic (4.15.0-47.50) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic
 initramfs-tools
```

Anyone got any ideas as to what I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Running auto-remove and clean worked for my situation.

`apt-get auto-remove && apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Comment: this did it for me

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a few hours of headache trying to reinstall the old version of Nvidia drivers to restore my display setup

Comment: This worked for me as well. I suspect, but can't confirm that I had older initrd images in /boot and it was full. I know that /boot for me was nearly full and I ignored the problem.  Now it's 55% usage so that's my guess.

Answer (score 22):

**Warning: do not do this if your hard drive is encrypted unless you know exactly what you're doing**

For me, it was an issue with the `initramfs-tools` package

I just did:

```
sudo apt remove initramfs-tools
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install initramfs-tools
```

Then I no longer received the error

@jameshibbard brought up an important point: if you use either full-drive encryption, or encrypt your initramfs output (squashfs vmlinuz pacakges in `/boot`) as is a new feature, please be careful as switching out versions of your `initramfs-tools` seem likely to make your system unbootable.

If you have no idea what that means, chances are your system is *not* encrypted, unless you remember selecting it during the install process.  I've noticed some graphical installers are including it as an option these days, including Ubuntu if I'm remembering correctly.

Do your due diligence.

Comment: Be careful when running these commands if using full-disk encryption. This can potentially nuke cryptsetup and leave the system unbootable (happened to me).

Comment: @JamesHibbard that's a good point, I hadn't thought of mentioning the danger of using on encrypted drive, as I don't use it.

Answer (score 11):

I had this error since more than a year. Now I found a solution.

```
cd ~
mkdir initramfs
cd initramfs
sudo cp -a /boot .
cd boot
sudo update-initramfs -ut -b .
sudo cp -a * /boot
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Explanation: /boot is on a different partition with insufficient space to perform the operation. Solution: do the update on a drive where there is sufficient space and copy back the results.

Comment: This is fantastic! I tried the other solutions, but none of them made a difference. This was exactly my problem. I have /boot on a different partition on a USB drive with encryption. For me, your solution didn't actually work, but the explanation gave me what I needed: `cd /boot` and `rm` all the old versions of what was in there, then `sudo apt update` (Adding an answer specific for this for visibility)

Comment: fundamentally this sounds like what I need (perform operation where I have space, then copy results), as I have a 260mb partition 1 that gets filled up and errors out. but this doesn't seem to work... can't do it on usb boot, as it is read-only fs, so update-initramfs throws errors. when doing it in chroot env, `-b .` doesn't seem to do anything, though... same error.

Comment: this one almost solved the problem for me but I needed to run it with "-k all" as well, resulting in this command: `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all -b .`. My scenario was that I updated kali to version 6.3.0 but the update process failed for some reason. So I ran kernel 5.14.0 to at least have a desktop, copied the /boot folder, ran "-k all" to generate the 6.3.0 with success, copy it back and it worked. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by Harald, the problem was insufficient space on the /boot partition.

His solution didn't work for me, but led me directly to what did:

`cd /boot`, then `ls` to look at the versions of the files already there. Then `rm` each of the files that have multiple versions, making sure to delete all but the newest, then `sudo apt update`

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for my encrypted drive. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt remove initramfs-tools
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install initramfs-tools
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This was the solution for me.

Comment: The first line (sudo apt remove initramfs-tools) helped me; none of the others did.

Comment: (-1) this removes `cryptsetup` which if you have your disk encrypted (like me) will not allow you to boot into your system. Do NOT do this

Comment: i often get this error if i use some of this:

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. My `/boot` partition was full. So, I was getting errors of `initframs` compilation when trying to run `apt-update`.
My solution was to remove old kernels in order to free up space, following the steps from Lekensteyn in:
[How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

This will list all the kernel images and headers currently installed:

```
~ % kernelver=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve $kernelver

linux-headers-5.4.0-94
linux-headers-5.4.0-94-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-96
linux-headers-5.4.0-96-generic
linux-headers-5.4.0-99
linux-headers-5.4.0-99-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-94-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic
linux-image-5.4.0-99-generic
```

You can purge the older `linux-headers` and `linux-image` packages by using `apt-get purge` with care (remember, not to delete the packages associated to the kernel you are using), for instance:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.4.0-94 linux-image-5.4.0-96 linux-headers-5.4.0-94 linux-headers-5.4.0-96
```

This should take care also of the matching `generic` packages.

Afterwards, I ran

```
sudo apt-get auto-remove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and the errors were fixed.

Comment: I did this too, but ran `sudo apt autoremove` instead of figuring out what to remove manually

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336174/ubuntu-12-04-update-to-the-3-8-kernel-fails) has this solution:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Additionally ensure this executable exists:

```
ls -alF /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck
```

returns this output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2468 Sep 18  2018 /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, done all that and the problem persists
`sudo dpkg --configure -a ..
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic (--configure):
 Errors ..processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-47-generic
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic`

the ll command returns the expected output.

Comment: I also did sudo apt autoremove

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on two separate machines today after doing an `apt update` and `apt upgrade` except mine was for linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic. (Ubuntu 18.04.2)

My fix was this (reproduced on both machines):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic.postinst
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

Then reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic
```

This will set the package to manually installed and will replace the *.postinst file.

Comment: Thank you sir, for the only solution that worked for me.

However, I changed it a little bit. I deleted all old linux-images- in ` /var/lib/dpkg/info`, except the latest one.

Then I did what you said.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a very similar issue when I did an `sudo apt autoremove` and it failed attempting to install kernel files for a kernel I don't have. My `uname -a` shows I'm using kernel version 5.0.0-20 and running `ls -al /boot` shows only this and the 5.0.0-17 kernel are installed. However, `apt` suddenly turned up errors and attempted to install files in my `/boot` for old kernels including 5.0.0-15, 4.18.0-17, 4.13.0-45. Which is weird.

So I figure that somehow they've altered the logic for `dkms` (or something related to `initramfs`) and it checks some other locations to see if kernels might be installed and then does updates on those kernels and replaces missing files.

I'm not sure exactly what fixed it but I did:

```
sudo apt purge *5.0.0-15* *4.18.0-17* *4.13.0-45* 
#check carefully that it's not removing anything you need though, this is a hammer to crack a nut

ls -al /lib/modules 
# which revealed lots of old module folders that I removed with ...
sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/4.* 
# and similarly for the 5.0.0-15 modules
```

Then I did:

```
ls -al /usr/src/ 
# which again showed old source trees that I pruned with
sudo rm -rf sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-4.*
```

Then I did:

```
locate -e 4.13.0 
# which found old kernel files in
ls -al /var/lib/initramfs-tools/ 
# so I removed with
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4*
```

I have problems with a very tight `/boot` folder for historical reasons and so removed old kernel files with:

```
sudo rm -i /boot/**4* 
# and similar for all but my current and next oldest kernels
# -i is interactive mode so you have to answer 'y' to remove
# that's a really useful safety check, 'sudo rm' is a dangerous tool!
```

Finally I ran:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Which finished as expected and returned the system to the expected state without attempting to install extraneous kernels. I did not test as I went along so can not guarantee which part fixed it, but it was not harmful to clear those old files out AFAICT.

Aside, checking my `/var/log/apt/history.log` file, this appears to be the beginning of this particular error:

```
Start-Date: 2019-07-01  17:59:10
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-tools-common:amd64 (4.15.0-52.56, 4.15.0-54.58)
End-Date: 2019-07-01  17:59:16

Start-Date: 2019-07-01  17:59:22
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-5.0.0-20-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-20.21~18.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-20-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-20.21~18.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.0.0-20-generic:amd64 (5.0.0-20.21~18.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04-edge:amd64 (5.0.0.17.73, 5.0.0.20.76), linux-image-extra-virtual-hwe-18.04-edge:amd64 (5.0.0.17.73, 5.0.0.20.76)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2019-07-01  18:00:10
```

But this may be a false flag as for me the limited /boot space can be the cause of the `error code (1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try purging unused kernels. If problem persists then remove all 'initrd' images with

```
sudo rm /boot/initrd.img*
```

then generate new 'initrd' images for all current existing kernels

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me. Ended up being that /boot was full.

Check boot partition space with `df -h`

Then free up some space with: [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the advice here and nothing worked. I fixed it by making sure that the boot/efi partition was mounted, which in my case it wasn't. /etc/fstab was not configured correctly due to the partuuid/uuid/lable not matching. Then I updated and upgraded with no errors, followed by updating grub and a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

[initramfs error when installing / updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136480/initramfs-error-when-installing-updating/1437887#1437887)

I continued to have this issue even after removing old kernels.  I was dealing with a 250 MB /boot partition which it seems is no longer big enough...

If you have tried everything else, an additional way to free up space on /boot may be to switch the compression algorithm that initramfs is using to create the initrd images.

Open up the following file:

```
sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
```

Check what COMPRESS is set to.  In my case it was:

```
COMPRESS=lz4
```

The xz algorithm will significantly reduce the size of the initrd.img-xxx image.  By simply making the following change, it was reduced by around 50%.

```
COMPRESS=xz
```