# Can't apt-get install ot remove any package. initramfs-tool failed

Tags: apt, 20.04, cryptswap

When I try install something, it seems my cryptswap got a problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package meofetch
t@pop-os:~$ sudo apt-get remove neofetch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  neofetch
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 339 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
(Reading database ... 358177 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing neofetch (7.0.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: Resume target cryptswap uses a key file
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initramfs error when installing / updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136480/initramfs-error-when-installing-updating)

Comment: Does your disk have encryption? If not does it use LVM or RAID?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207958/error-24-write-error-cannot-write-compressed-block)

Answer (score 3):

The error message that is reported in the question only occurs in 20.04. Here is a workaround.

1. Boot into [Recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/) and wait until the loading of the cryptswapfile times out.
2. Go to a root shell (the second entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and comment out the following lines in `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` by preceding each line with a `#` character.

   `/etc/fstab` :

   ```
    /dev/mapper/cryptswap none swap defaults 0 0
   ```

   `/etc/crypttab` :

   ```
   cryptswap /cryptswapfile /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256
   ```
3. Run  `swapoff -a && update-initramfs -u`.
4. Uncomment the lines in fstab and crypttab that you commented out, and reboot with `sudo reboot`.

Comment: Thank you, that works!

Comment: @TeddyzxcvPan If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Answer (score 0):

For people with similar message, but also talking about the RESUME variable that would be set to a wrong UUID:

Just remove the automatically set RESUME variable in resume file of initramfs-tools (`sudo rm /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`), or update it to the correct UUID of your swap partition.