# The installation of the package failed initramfs-tool

Tags: software-installation, update-manager, error-handling

When I am updating my Kubuntu 20.04 via Discover I am getting the message

> The installation of the package failed Error while installing package: initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

What does this mean and what can I do to solve the issue?

---

Also, yes, my logic volumes are encrypted.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1215354/402358 explicitly  warns to not follow the respective solution, so I am not sure whether the (other) solutions of [initramfs error when installing / updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136480/initramfs-error-when-installing-updating) are a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just had too little space on the boot partition. Following https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1974-how-to-fix-a-full-boot-partition-on-linux solved the issue.

Comment: avoid using plasma-discover https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/packagekit/+bug/1914278