# Ubuntu won't update: "The package linux-modules-5.19.0-32-generic needs to be reinstalled", but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: updates, 22.04, update-manager

Every time I try to upgrade packages with *sudo apt upgrade* I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-modules-5.19.0-32-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Gnome-software won't run. If I try I get a red circle with a white line across it in the system tray with an error message:
[image: screengrab of error message]

I've been trying to fix it by following instructions in this post: [I am having a problem with the package manager on 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040684/i-am-having-a-problem-with-the-package-manager-on-18-04-lts). Obviously this is for a different version of Ubuntu to the one I am struggling with, but the problem appears to be the same.

I've downloaded the closest .deb package that matches the missing package from [https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-modules-5.19.0-41-generic_5.19.0-41.42~22.04.1_amd64.deb.html](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-modules-5.19.0-41-generic_5.19.0-41.42%7E22.04.1_amd64.deb.html).

That was the closest I could get but trying to install it locally with `sudo apt install` just throws the same error message above.

This information might be useful. Output of ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 838 May 20 15:15 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Output of uname -a:

```
Linux slug 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

Output of sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a:

```
Unknown option: a
```

In the comments Marco suggested a corrected form of this code as

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

That produces no output at all. Just another line in the terminal with ~$.

Output of dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|h|m]' as requested by **nobody**:

```
ii  linux-generic-hwe-22.04                    5.15.0.60.58                            amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-58                    5.15.0-58.64                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic            5.15.0-58.64                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-60                    5.15.0-60.66                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic            5.15.0-60.66                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04            5.15.0.60.58                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic              5.15.0-43.46                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic              5.15.0-56.62                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-57-generic              5.15.0-57.63                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic              5.15.0-58.64                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic              5.15.0-60.66                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04              5.15.0.60.58                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-43-generic            5.15.0-43.46                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic            5.15.0-56.62                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-57-generic            5.15.0-57.63                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.15.0-58-generic            5.15.0-58.64                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.15.0-60-generic            5.15.0-60.66                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iHR linux-modules-5.19.0-32-generic            5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1                    amd64        (no description available)
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-43-generic      5.15.0-43.46                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-56-generic      5.15.0-56.62                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-57-generic      5.15.0-57.63                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-58-generic      5.15.0-58.64                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-60-generic      5.15.0-60.66                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: The command is `dpkg --configure -a` or `apt-get -f install`. not the one you mentioned.

Comment: besides this, the problem you describe is not clear. Which error do you get from which command?

Comment: Please add `dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|h|m]'`to your question through [edit] We can remove the packages from your system that requires it.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. 
@guiverc, sorry I don't know how the 18.04 tag got there. I've removed it as my problem is with 22.04.

Comment: Thanks again, more info and output added. NC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this is bruteforce the package is not longer available.

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq linux-modules-5.19.0-32-generic
```

This way it could be that some parts of the package can remain on your system.

More force

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all linux-modules-5.19.0-32-generic
```

To avoid such problems a configured apt not to remove downloaded packages

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs 
# Heruntergeladene Pakete behalten.
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
APT::Get::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
Binary::apt-get::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
```

So i can use my local cache under /var/cache/apt/archives/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the solution. I ran both lines. Only the 1st was necessary, I think. Now upgrading.