# Ubuntu package manager error: E: The package linux-headers-5.15.0-58 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates

Every time I try to install a package like using the command below

```
sudo apt install git
```

I get the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-5.15.0-58 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I am currently on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I've been trying to fix it with commands from this post: [Ubuntu won't update: "The package linux-modules-5.19.0-32-generic needs to be reinstalled", but I can't find an archive for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468636/ubuntu-wont-update-the-package-linux-modules-5-19-0-32-generic-needs-to-be-re). Obviously, the issue in that thread is from a different version.I have also tried other commands from this thread: [Linux-Headers Reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064674/linux-headers-reinstall)

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: You've not mentioned what OS/release you're actually using; I see reference for it for *focal* (20.04), is what what you're using?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-headers-5.15.0-58&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  as 5.15 is used by multiple releases.  I'd start with `sudo apt update` & check all lines of output are there, no warnings/errors & no missing lines etc.. ie. check your sources after you work out what OS/release you're using (we're limited to details you tell us)

Comment: Attempts to fetch updates through sudo apt update work but using sudo apt upgrade does not and results in the same package error.

Comment: You have two options: You can 1) Download the correct package from launchpad.net, reinstall it, then remove with full automatic cleanup using apt, or 2) Force-uninstall the package, and clean up all the installed files manually. Both methods work if done properly. Your link does the easy part of #2 (it skips the cleanup). It's unclear what problem you are encountering since the question does not include complete input/output of whatever you tried.

Comment: Don't comment on your own question. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1484465/edit) instead to add information and answer questions. Comments are intended to help you refine and improve your question until it is answerable. Then somebody will answer it.