# A Problem Ocurred While Checking for Updates [Ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: apt

It keeps appearing this red signal in the top right of my screen with this error. If I run `sudo apt update` all I got is:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found           
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Thanks.

Comment: please edit your question to include your OS and version

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074763/error-when-trying-sudo-apt-get-update-python-related) should help you fix your problem. Please check, if `ls -la /usr/bin/python` is pointing to python 2.x or 3.x first.

Comment: it points to 2.7 and runned sudo apt-get -f install but then happens the same...

Comment: now I think it goes beyond this. python may be totally broken because I cant open any software or update program without saying that it is misses something ou there no such file or directory... neither terminal. i'm using xterm