# Why I got error after Python upgrade? /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python

I tried everything,I still have the error

```
sudo apt update
```

shows

```
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I tried back and fort Pyhton2,3. Now

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18

python3 --version
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Mar  2 09:37 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3662032 Jul  1  2022 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5494584 Nov 14 13:59 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Nov 14 13:59 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5762192 Dec  7 02:11 /usr/bin/python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Jan 25 09:33 /usr/bin/python3-futurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 Jan 25 09:33 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    5902 Jan 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3-wsdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2555 Apr 14  2020 /usr/bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     314 Apr 14  2020 /usr/bin/python-argcomplete-tcsh3
```

This [error when trying sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074763/error-when-trying-sudo-apt-get-update-python-related) relates to 2018 year.
After

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1

which python3
```

shows

```
/usr/bin/python3

which python3.9
/usr/bin/python3.9
```

One other consequence is that I can not open Terminal(Terminator) form Gnome.

how to fix this? Problems persist again.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? How did you "upgrade" python? Upgrading the default python version often breaks things.

Comment: @popey 20.04 Ubuntu,I just install python3.9 with pip3 install. I need that for Ansible.

Comment: There's usually a symlink from `/usr/bin/python3` to whatever the default version is. You could re-create it manually with something like `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3` to get you out of this hole.

Comment: The default python for your system is `python3.8` ... Link it back to `python3` as shown in @popey's comment above ... And don't ever alter the default system python version or else that will happen again and it's not always fixable ... So if you managed to fix it with the command above, consider it a lesson learned ... Ubuntu relies on the default system python version ... It's an essential part of the OS and not just an interpreter to run your python scripts.

Comment: Related and might help: https://askubuntu.com/q/1448702